# How to display the image of the related node in the Message template?

Tags: templates, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I have the Message module installed on my site. I created a message template for the new node created in my sub theme.

[image]

I would like to display the image of the node in the message template with the style `diaporama_lg_50`.

I tested the code below with TWIG but it does not work :

```
{{ message.field_node_reference.entity.field_article_image | image_style('diaporama_lg_50') }}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure `message.field_node_reference.entity.field_article_image` is correct? Often I find that file/image fields are arrays so it may be `message.field_node_reference.entity.field_article_image[0]`. Of course, I am just going be memory here. Try debugging  the template with the kint module that comes with the devel module. I think you can see all the template variables with {{ kint() }} in the template. Or you could do a preprocess function and check things out there.

Comment: @2pha Thank you, but it does not work. How can I find the right code with Kint ?

Comment: [debugging twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates)